# TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/gson/JsonPrimitive.class

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, odoo, twitter-digits

**Scenario:** build.gradle

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile project(':intro-slider-lib')
compile project(':parallax-effect-lib')
compile project(':odoo-rpc-v3')
compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:1.10.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
}
```

**Error:**

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/gson/JsonPrimitive.class
```

**Problem:**

```
compile project(':odoo-rpc-v3')
compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:1.10.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

Both odoo-rpc and digits above,have a gson module in it as a result of which its showing duplicate error.

**Solutions attempted:**

- attempt no. 1

I excluded the gson module from digit using this:

```
    compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:1.10.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson'
}
```

but another miracle happened (Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded)

Note:  multiDexEnabled true  is set aswell

- attempt no.2

I tried to exclude gson module from both odoo-rpc and Digits and inserted only one gson module but failed as i couldn't exclude gson module from odoo-rpc. Here is the snippet:

```
 compile (project(':odoo-rpc-v3')){
exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson'
}
 compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:1.10.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson'
}
```

- attempt no.3

Saved one of the jar file (odoo-rpc) locally and deleted the gson file and then i inserted that jar file in dependency like this:

```
compile files('C:/Users/tonys/AndroidStudioProjects/Hello/classes.jar')
```

but made no progress. :(

Please help me to check whether my concept is right or wrong.
Thanks in advance.